# why server not respond to some ajax query in some devices?

Tags: ajax, laravel

In my program , when client send an ajax query to my server , it send back respond to client . But for some devices (about 1% of them) , respond can not be received in client or perhaps client would have problem itself (not clear for me) . when this happen and client change its device(desktop PC , laptop , tablet , mobile) , problem will be solved . it is not related to browser type (happen with chrome,mozilla,...) . is there any setting in device or browser? Why this happen? thanks

Comment: which language you are using for back-end?

Comment: laravel 5.2 for back-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a middleware and apply that middleware on all the routes. Then, replace the function of middleware as follows:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
    return $next($request);
}
```